# Asserting that response object contains certain element

Tags: javascript

I'm quite new to JavaScript and have been tasked with a couple things. I am getting response headers and within the error function want an if statement that will check for its existence and return an error if it is incorrect or non existent. So on a correct response the object would be `data.info.http_code = 200`. If something goes wrong, `http_code` doesn't exist in the response, so I can't do an if statement based on `http_code`, and I can't figure out how to do an if on the non existence of `http_code`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out what I needed was typeof...... data always has a result, but it's hard to know what will be included with the result. So it looks like this: I want to catch a very basic error for something in there being left undefined.

```
if(typeof data.result == "undefined"){
if (d.error) d.error(data);
} else {
if (d,success) d.success(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (data != undefined && data.info != undefined && data.info.http_code == 200) {
    //It's ok here
}
else {
    //When either the code is different from 200 or doesn't exist
}
```